# embed youtube in c/gtk application

Tags: gtk, youtube-api, gdata-api

I want to develop an application, for searching and watching youtube videos, in C language with GTK for UserInterface. Does API's available for embedding Youtube into C application ?
Can I use GData for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into gstreamer, which provides a youtube plugin. However, the standard GNOME video player, Totem, already does exactly what you're after.

Comment: Ya, It does, but it uses Python for that.... I dont want to use Python. Is it possible to achieve without using Python/PHP/java ?

Comment: If it's using Python, then I'm sure it's using the Python bindings to gstreamer and gtk. It should be relatively straightforward to convert that to C.

Comment: Can gstreamer support likes/dislikes/subscriptions/views?